# md-autcomplete form populated with contents of another md-autocomplete form?

Tags: angularjs, md-autocomplete, angularjs-material

I have two forms on a web page.

One form wraps around a `md-autocomplete` search bar along with a header on the page; the other around another `md-autocomplete`entity on the page itself.

The forms have different names. However, upon loading the page, the contents of the form on the page are duplicated within the form on the top of the page. Any idea on why this behavior may be occurring?

Comment: Can you post your code or create a Pen or Fiddle?

Comment: thanks for commenting, @camden_kid. Figured it out shortly after posting -- when using multiple md-autocompletes on the same page, it's necessary to name your md-search-texts differently... Silly mistake!